# Promise continues after error

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, promise, async-await

I have some async code that needs to stop in case of error but keeps executing:

```
async saveCoupons({ state, rootState, dispatch, commit }) {
    const promises = []
    state.userCoupons.forEach(coupon => { 
        if (coupon.isNew && coupon.isUpdated) {
            // if the user is creating a new coupon
            promises.push(Vue.axios.post('/api_producer/coupons.json', coupon, { params: { token: coupon.token } }))
        } else if (!coupon.isNew && coupon.isUpdated) {
            // if the user is updating the coupon
            promises.push(Vue.axios.patch(`api_producer/coupons/${coupon.id}/`, coupon, { params: { token: coupon.token } }))
        }
    })
    try {
        await Promise.all(promises)
        dispatch('utilities/showModal', 'success', { root: true })
        dispatch('fetchProducerCoupons')
    } catch (err) {
        let couponToken = err.request.responseURL.split('token=')[1]
        commit('ADD_ERROR_ON_COUPON', couponToken)
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

This is how the code is currently structured, it works, but I realize it's terrible. What I need to do is stop the excution of

```
dispatch('utilities/showModal', 'success', { root: true })
dispatch('fetchProducerCoupons')
```

In case one of the api calls fails. I wanted to catch the error inside the forEach so I already have the item available and I can add the error to it right away as opposed to doing it after (which is what I'm doing now with `{ params: { token: coupon.token } }`.

Comment: Do the requests need to be fired in parallel or could they be fired after another?

Comment: No it doesn't really matter. As long as I can catch the error of the call right from within the forEach, so I can attach the error to the item and than display it in the front end.

If it does success than all it's doing is showing success modal and than refreshing the items by fetching them again

Comment: Add a .catch to each one of the Promise calls and "throw" the parameters you need to your error handler.

Comment: @LuizChagasJr it's still executing the rest of the code at the bottom this way, unless I'm doing something wrong. Could you actually write it down please?

Comment: If any of the `promises` is rejected, then the `await` will trigger an exception and your dispatches won't be executed. Are the promises not rejected when the api calls fail?

Comment: I would just make them run one after another with array reduce. (google: reduce promise), that means as soon as one fails you get that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way would be to wrap the `Vue.axios` requests into your own Promise. Then, if the requests fail, you have the coupon tokens in your error.

Something like

```js
const promises = [];

promises.push(
  Vue.axios.post('/api_producer/coupons.json', coupon)
    .catch(() => { throw new Error(coupon.token) }));
    
Promise.all(promises).catch(tokens => {
  tokens.forEach(token => {
    // Commit/handle errorous token
  });
});
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Yes this works. I'm only using `catch` in the api call, as I don't need to do anything on success, and in the `Promise.all(promises)` i have the `then()` to execute the 2 functions at the end of the code. 
I will post again what I have. I'm wondering if there's a way to make all of this using await/async, that I like more than Promises

Comment: @Bergi, what do you mean?

Comment: @Giacomo, yes of course you could do that. You just need a 'global' variable which will tell you in the end, whether any call failed or not and only then execute your `dispatch` actions.

Comment: @Bergi, okay, I understand what you mean. Just as I understood OP, he wants to access the `coupon.token` in the catch. However, if the `Vue.axios` request fails, he still won't know which token it was. Therefore I wrapped it into another Promise. Or is this handled by `Vue.axios`?

Comment: It's fine to produce a transformed promise, but it's not fine to wrap it in `new Promise` for that. Just do `promises.push(axios.post(…).chain(() => { throw new Error(coupon.token); }))`

Comment: @Bergi, gotcha.

Comment: Fixed. Not using the constructor anymore, but throwing an error so the promise can be chained further.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your api call in another promise and check the status. Something like this:

```
promises.push(

  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    Vue.axios.post('/api_producer/coupons.json', coupon, { params: { token: coupon.token } })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        coupon.error = true;
        reject();
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });

  })
);
```

The `reject` will keep these two lines from being executed:

```
  dispatch('utilities/showModal', 'success', { root: true })
  dispatch('fetchProducerCoupons')
```

Comment: but this still doesn't allow me to get access to the error right in the forEach, it has to be outside

Comment: ahh!! I tried that too but i was missing the `new Promise`, not understanding why that's the solution now but it's working

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: I didn't know this was an antipattern, thanks for bringing it to my attention

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Moritz Schmitz v. Hülst & sklingler93 for the help, I restructured the code and it's working.

I'm wondering if there's a way to write all of this using only async/await... If anybody has an idea, would love to see it :)

```
saveCoupons({ state, rootState, dispatch, commit }) {
    const promises = []
    state.userCoupons.forEach(coupon => {          
        if (coupon.isNew && coupon.isUpdated) {
            // if the user is creating a new coupon
            promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                Vue.axios.post('/api_producer/coupons.json', coupon)
                    .then(response => resolve(response))
                    .catch(err => {
                        reject(err)
                        commit('ADD_ERROR_ON_COUPON', coupon.token)
                    })                        
            }))
        } else if (!coupon.isNew && coupon.isUpdated) {
            // if the user is updating the coupon
            promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                Vue.axios.patch(`api_producer/coupons/${coupon.id}/`, coupon)
                    .then(response => resolve(response))
                    .catch(err => {
                        reject(err)
                        commit('ADD_ERROR_ON_COUPON', coupon.token)
                    })
            }))
        }
    })
    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(() => {
            dispatch('utilities/showModal', 'success', { root: true })
            dispatch('fetchProducerCoupons')
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
},
```

Comment: This code cannot work. The promises in your array are never settled

Comment: Isn't `Promise.all(promises)...` taking care of that? @Bergi

Comment: No. `Promise.all` does not settle any promises other than the one it returns. In all of those `new Promise` executor callbacks, you never call `resolve` or `reject`!

Comment: Ok I added `.then(response => resolve(response))` in each new Promise. Is that it?

Comment: [No](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it). Now you're just ignoring errors.

Comment: @Bergi updated again, the catch. Was that it? If not I'm really not understanding

Comment: Better, but still employing the antipattern. Btw, do you want to `commit` for each error that happens or only once?

Comment: @Bergi commit for each error because I than show it inside the actual element in the html. Let's say I have 3 boxes with the coupon, one of them is updated, user clicks the save (a general button for all of them). The forEach goes through them and checks if the property of `isUpdated` is true it makes a patch request, but in case the coupon name was already used by another user it throws the error and I need to display it inside the box. 
Otherwise if there are no errors, everything is good, shows success modal, fetch coupons again and that's it. Makes sense?